# define variable if panel data takes a value once

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have a panel data set identified by an id variable and one specific string variable with different values for each time period (weekly). Not every id is represented in every week (new can come and older can vanish).

I created a dummy when this variable contains a specific term, but it only captures the single appearance in a week. What I would like to have is that each id has a specific dummy that indicates whether the term is contained in the string variable in at least one week's occurrence. So in case in week 34 id x contains the term, i'd like to have a dummy for all the other weeks as well, that shows a "1", as the term once was contained for id x

I tried formatting as an `xtset` and replacing via `F.`, but that didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is what you want, given that you have already created the `term` variable set to 1 if the string contains the term, and (I assume) 0 otherwise.

```
by id (time), sort: egen newterm = max(term)
replace term = newterm
drop newterm
```

The `by id (time), sort: ...` command will run the `egen` separately for each `id`. The `egen` will find the maximum value of `term` for each `id`, so `newterm` will be 1 if any `term` is 1.

Comment: `bysort id (term) : replace term = term[_N]` appears to be a reduction of this.

Comment: Agreed, but then I would to follow it by `sort id time` to put it in the familiar order (or at least the order that's familiar to me for panel data).

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the logic. As far as I understand it, this should also work if not every single (id) is contained in every (time) as a observation.

Comment: @NickCox: I guess term[_N] is the last observation of term or is it the highest? In my case the term was contained in any time of the panel, so not necessarily at the end of the panel. Thus, the maximum seems safer for me. Is sorting by term necessary in order to ensure that the last value _N is the highest?

Comment: No need to guess. Read up on `by:` e.g. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004 and experiment with simple datasets to see what happens. Your misgivings are unfounded.  Assuming that `term` by construction is 0 or 1, any occurrences of 1 will be sorted to the end of each block of observations, so this is then a safe (and fast) way of finding the maximum. If the problem is not as you have told us, the advice may differ.